# Ember store data to django backend

Tags: django, ember.js

I'm new to Ember and I'm trying to communicate with a django server via RESTful API. So far I have managed to get the information from the server but if I try to send some information back I get a "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." error.

In the resources of Chrome's developer tools I can see that I don't have any cookie. I've read that I should the "X-CSRFToken": "cookie" in my adapter but since I don't have a cookie I don't know what to do.

So I' m in dead end...

Here is my code:

Server Response:

```
 [{"username":"user1","password":"123","email":"user1@example.com"},        
 {"username":"user2","password":"456","email":"user2@example.com"}]
```

Ember Model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
   username: DS.attr(),
   password: DS.attr(), 
   email: DS.attr()
});
```

Ember Adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

   export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '/api',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',

  headers: {
    username: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX'
}, 

buildURL: function(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {

    var url = this._super(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query);

    return url + "/";
}


});
```

Ember Serializer:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'username'
});

Ember Route: import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model() {
       return this.store.findAll('account');
}
});
```

Ember Controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    actions: {

   signup(){
    console.log('My username is: ', this.get('username'));
    console.log('My password is: ', this.get('password'));
    console.log('My email is: ', this.get('email'));

    var account = this.store.createRecord('account', {
            username: this.get('username'),
            password: this.get('password'),
            email: this.get('email')
    });

    account.save();

}
}
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue.
The problem was that I was using http://localhost:4200/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:4200/ and that's why I couldn't find django's cookie.

As soon as I found django's cookie, I just add an attribute to the header of the adapter.

My new adapter is shown below:

Ember Adapter:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: '/api',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',

 headers: {
    "X-CSRF-Token": 'django token',
    username: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX'
 }, 

 buildURL: function(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {

    var url = this._super(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query);

    return url + "/";
 }


 });
```

Comment: If you are using Django REST Framework, consider trying ember-django-adapter https://github.com/dustinfarris/ember-django-adapter